# CSS selector to find a html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css-selectors, sizzle

Can some body help me with sample code or api which address my need. My need is similar to xpath of an element I would like find an element using "CSS Selector". Any pointer towards this will be of great help thanks
jeevitesh

Comment: We would gladly help you if u encounter a difficulty with your code, but your question is waaaay too general. I suggest you learn css first.

Comment: For starters, visit http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp.

Comment: Your questions is to general. You should have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started to learn the CSS basics.

Comment: or if you are trying it out practically please include the code or html with more explanation

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.someClass')
```

or

```
$('#someId')
```

or

```
$('.outerClass .innerClass')
```

or

better use native js

```
document.querySelectorAll('.outerClass .innerClass')
```

P.S.

```
$('[SOME CSS SELECTOR]')
document.querySelectorAll('[SOME CSS SELECTOR]')
```